# Can we use Robot framework with cucumber framework java?

Tags: selenium, robotframework, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am completely new to testing framework. In my team we are using cucumber framework(Java) with selenium for UI testing.

Here someone from other team suggested we can use Robot framework(based on selenium) as well.

**So my question is, can we integrate Robot framework with Cucumber.**

If So could you please provide me link as well where there is example to use robot and cucumber fw integrated way.

Comment: But why? What problem are you trying to solve with integrating Cucumber and RF?

Comment: @pavelsaman .. I have to do UI testing(could be java swing UI or web UI). for UI testing I am using Selenium with Cucumber.
I also want to know can we use Robot FW with cucumber for UI testing. my question might not make any sense to you. but i have to know if it is possible or not. i can't see any example also in google.

Comment: But that's not an answer to why. You're using Cucumber and Selenium. RF is a different product. Not seeing any examples on Google is perhaps an answer to your question.

Comment: Since we're talking about software, yes, it's possible. However, likely nobody has done it before so it would require a tremendous amount of work, depending on exactly what you mean by "integrate".